# How to convert BCP exported .xls file to actual Excel format file?

Tags: excel, t-sql, batch-file

I have a batch file with the statement below. The export works fine and results are in the file Corp.xls. However, when I try to open this file, I get a warning 'The file you are trying to open is in a different format that that specified by the file extenion ..........

When I open the file and try to 'Save As', I find that it is in Text-tab delimted format. 
Is there any way to convert such a file to excel without having to open the file - i.e from the batch file ?

Note: The batch file is very comples. Given below is just a modified snippet.

```
    BCP "exec DBname.dbo.sp_abc '201503' " queryout "\\ABC\3_MAR\Corp.xls" -T -c -S SCC-SLDB
```

Comment: Not in pure batch; the XLS format is not conducive to external manipulation. Even the XLSX format is _extremely_ complicated (although admittedly easier) to manipulate, and that's just an archive containing XML files. The best thing to do is to convert the tabs to commas and save the file as a .csv file, which can also be opened with batch.

Comment: Or you could export it as Corp.tsv and then Excel should open it with no warning.